# Outer regularity of Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to show the outer regularity property of the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$ i.e. that For $E\in \mathcal{L}^n$ $\mathcal{m}(E)=\inf\{\mathcal{m}(U):E\supset E, U \text{ open}\}$.

I can see that there exists a cover of rectangles ${B_i}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\mathcal{m}(E)\leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathcal{m}(B_i) \leq \mathcal{m}(E)+\epsilon \quad \forall \epsilon >0$.

Now I don't know if the rectangles $B_i$ are open so I need to construct an open rectangle with a measure close to $B_i$. I can apply the outer regularity property of $\mathbb{R}$ on each side of $B_i$ to show that $\mathcal{m}(\hat B_i)\leq \mathcal{m}(U_i)\leq \mathcal{m}(\hat B_i)+\epsilon$ where without loss of generality, $\hat B_i$ is a side of $B_i$ where $U_i$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$.

**How would I then combine the $\hat U_i$ to create an open set which has measure close enough to $\mathcal{m}(E)$?**

I have attached the proof of this claim from Folland which I am unable to follow for this reason.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For things like this, the standard trick in measure theory is not to use $m(\hat B^i)\le m(U_i)\le m(\hat B^i)+\varepsilon$ but to observe that $\varepsilon$ can depend on $i$. So you actually choose $U_i$ such that $m(\hat B^i)\le m(U_i)\le m(\hat B^i)+2^{-i}\varepsilon$, and when summing up, you observe that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty2^{-i}\varepsilon=\varepsilon$.

Comment: In the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$ for example, if I have some arbitrary rectangle $R=R_1\times R_2$ which may not be open, how can I justify the claim that there exists an open set $U$ such that $\mathcal{m}(R)\leq \mathcal{m}(U) \leq \mathcal{m}(R) + \epsilon$? Is it because there exist open $R_1\subset U_1$ and $R_2\subset U_2$ such that $\mathcal{m}(R)=\mathcal{m}(R_1)\times \mathcal{m}(R_2)\leq (\mathcal{m}(U_1)+\epsilon)(\mathcal{m}(U_2)+\epsilon)$ and I can make some clever choice of $\epsilon$ for this to hold?